# Trying to compile a book written 2011 from files sent by publisher

Tags: book-design

In response to a request to a publisher for a pdf version of a 2011 book I purchased, the publisher sent me collection of three folders: one containing .tex files for each of the chapters, as well as .sty files and a .cls file; another containing several more folders, each related to a particular font used in the book; and a third folder containing several more folders, each containing graphics files associated to a specific chapter of the book.

I've been using LateX (via Aquamacs) for many years, but have never been involved in writing a book, so am not sure where to start when it comes to trying the render the book from the files I was given.  I ran LaTeX on a main.tex file that is very simple and looks like this:

```latex
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
%
%\tableofcontents
%

\include{00-Author-Preliminaries}

\mainmatter


\include{01-Author-c01}
\include{02-Author-c02}
\include{03-Author-c03}
\include{04-Author-c04}
\include{05-Author-c05}
\include{06-Author-c06}
\include{07-Author-c07}
\include{08-Author-c08}
\include{09-Author-Conclusion}


\backmatter

\appendix
\include{10-Author-Reading}
\appendixend
\include{11-Author-Index}
\end{document}
```

but that didn't work. The first error produced was:

> LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
> there is probably something wrong with the class file.

and soon after:

> Undefined control sequence.
> l.4 \frontmatter

along with many similar errors for other unrecognized commands.

I'm sure I don't know what I'm doing, but given that the files date from 2011 and earlier, could it be that I need to get my hands on a legacy LaTeX engine from when the files were written?  Or should I still be able render the book since I have all the relevant files?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers!

Edit: Here also is the file @UlrikeFischer asked about in the comments, that is, the only file in which the `documentclass{...}` command appears.

```latex
%\documentclass[draftrules,draft,revise,watermark]{../setup/Author}
\documentclass[final,watermark]{Author}

%\usepackage{qtree}

\addtolength\textheight{.1pt}%


\let\newterm=\textit
\let\textex=\textit
\let\textti=\textit
\let\jtitle=\textit
\let\btitle=\emph
\newcommand{\plan}[1]{\relax}
\let\concept=\textsc
\let\licensor=\textbf
\let\npi=\textit
%\newcommand{\cat}[1]{.#1}
\newcommand{\horline}[1]{\underline{\makebox[#1]{}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\starhere}
\settowidth{\starhere}{*}
\newcommand{\starspace}{\makebox[\starhere]{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Commands to set up an environment for examples
%% with running example numbers.
\newcounter{memory}
\newenvironment{exx}
   {\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\theenumi)}
    \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii.}
    \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{5mm}}
                \item
                \begin{enumerate}
                \addtocounter{enumi}{\value{memory}}}
   {\setcounter{memory}{\value{enumi}}
    \end{enumerate}\end{list}}

\newenvironment{abc}
 {
  \begin{enumerate}
 }
 {
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\newcommand{\bref}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\let\exref=\bref
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\ArtDir{../Art/}%

%%%%%%% For running head updation %%%%
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\clearpage
                    \thispagestyle{plain}
                    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                        \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{Book Title}%
                    \markright{\MakeLowercase{\letterspacefftn{#2}}}
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \gdef\@chaptertitle{#2}
                    \@afterheading}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Looks to me like part of `main.tex` is missing. A LaTeX document should never start with `\begin{document}`; most often, they begin with `\documentclass{...}`, following by a preamble. That hasn't changed since 2011. Did you edit `main.tex` at all? Are there any other `.tex` files besides the ones that start with numbers?

Comment: You could try adding `\documentclass{name-of-cls-file}` at the beginning with the actual name of the `.cls` file there, but most likely, there are other pieces and/or options missing too.

Comment: Thanks, @frabjous: That's actually how the file starts.  I'll add the `documentclass{...}` command and see what happens.

Comment: check if there is a wrapper file with a \documentclass command.

Comment: That was very helpful, @frabjous: You're right, there are more error, but it looks like they're easier to track down now, and at least I have readable text instead of the symbol salad I had before.

Comment: the file you show could never have worked, this is not due to a change in latex, you are missing the start of the file. Or more likely the file you show is not the top level file to pass to latex check there is not a fil say `main.tex` with `\documentclass... \usepackge....  \input{the file you show here}`

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer and @DavidCarlisle: It turns out the only file with a `\documentclass{...}` command is a file that doesn't reference any other files, and no files reference the `main.tex` file, so it seems I wasn't sent a working set of files.  As I mentioned earlier, by adding the `\documentclass{...}` command I can get the text rendered, but the file relationships have been garbled and despite the font folders, there are many "can't find this, so will substitute this" errors.  I'll keep at it, but it looks like I simply wasn't given the collection that was used to render the book.

Comment: Show the file with the documentclass command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I just edited my question to include it, too, but it seems intended just for producing the running headers.

Comment: Just a guess.  The publisher has an internal-only "driver file" with a `\documentclass` that they don't release publicly.  They produce pdf files with that, and apply running heads later.  (A similar technique was used by the publisher I used to work for, but only to put together (republished) "collected works"  or symposium proceedings.  It wasn't intended to be used by an author.)  But in a case like that, each individual file had its own `\documentclass`.  You need to find out what that is so the book will be set with the desired style.